# Story about a secret agent or spy with skill set by personas

Tags: story-identification, novel

This is a novel I've read in the 90's. I have a very dim recollection of most the below, so some of this may be dead wrong.

An operative/secret agent/spy has to complete one or more missions. When faced with a problem, his handler can unlock personas - lover, thief, fighter, etc. However, he does not have a say in unlocking these. He may need to justify or they can decide based on what they see through his eyes?

Toward the end of the novel he assaults an evil lair (industrial complex?) in the wilderness or swamp. His handlers are possibly taken out by someone else  but he goes freelance or retires.

At the end of the book, all his abilities/personas are unlocked for his own use (**definitely remember this**). This may include super human speed due to missing neurons?

Answer (score 10):

Could this be a misremembering of [All My Sins Remembered](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/h/joe-w-haldeman/all-my-sins-remembered.htm) by Joe Haldeman? It is about a secret agent who has "personality overlays" to aid his missions, mostly for maintaining his cover. One episode has him on a jungle planet where he must fight brutally all night to survive. I don't think he attacks his handlers, rather he suffers a nervous breakdown.

Comment: I think you got it. I'll check it out and mark as solved.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't it. Similar, but Otto dies in the end and my hero is freed and gains all the abilities.

Comment: Yes, it was really only similar by the premise and jungle/swamp episode. Too bad